# jquery fail not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am quite new to jquery/ajax, but I am trying to use `done` instead of `success` and `fail` instead of `error`. It does what I want for `done`, but `fail` does not seem to be firing? The code below works, but if I change `error` to `fail` it does not set value of callback to `Error`.

```
done: function() {
    callback("Success");
},
error: function() {
    callback("Error");
}
```

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `done()` and `fail()` are methods, not ajax method option. See [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: If it matters, I am trying to catch a 400 Bad request from the server. And as said, it works for done, but not fail.

Comment: Regarding your posted code, it doesn't work for `done` too...

Comment: Ah, I might be a noob :) But epascarellos answer did the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fail is part of the [Promise interface](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) so you need to do it like this

```
$.ajax({})
   .done( function() {} )
   .fail( function() {} )
   .always( function() {} );
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!